# Consulta de mysql erronea

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cuando quiero realizar esta consulta me la marca como erronea[[image: Ahi realizo la consulta desde sql para ver si esta bien y tambien como se ve desde el codigo][1]]

Comment: Saludos. Revisa la sintaxis; te hace falta el campo(s) de la tabla que deseas mostrar, es decir, lo que va entre SELECT y FROM. Adicionalmente te sugiero no incluyar ENTERs en la consulta; usar una linea de cadena y concatena; es decir String sql=" SELECT CAMPO1, campo2,... " + (en vez de ENTER) + "campoN FROM " +(en vez de ENTER) .... asi por el estilo para armar el SQL que ejecutaras.

Comment: Me funciono con el where, con el AND no me esta funcionando

Comment: Debes indicar que columnas vas a recuperar luego del Select o en su defecto usar el operador *

Comment: Al final de cada linea o al inicio de la siguiente agrega un espacio (barra espaciadora) puede este resultado algo como rec_tag_id = 5AND rec_modo_id=1 ya agregando el espacio que menciono te quedara rec_tag_id = 5 AND rec_modo_id=1

Comment: Te falta un = en la segunda condición

Comment: Las imágenes no se ven bien, sugiero que para este tipo de problemas, en vez de imagen pongas el texto del código que estás usando, así como el texto del mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

En el SELECT no estas haciendo ninguna seleccion por lo que es imposible que funcione.
para el resto pruebalo asi

```
SELECT 
FROM recetas
WHERE (rec_tag.id = 5) AND (rec_modo_id = 1);
```

Copia el codigo en tu pregunta entre {} para que se vea mejor ya que en la imagen apenas se distingue nada